# Processing 3 vs Processing.js?

Tags: processing, processing.js

I'd like to know what works in Processing 3 but doesn't work or isn't supported (yet) in Processing.js? Seems like many of the new examples in Processing 3's GUI don't work once converted to js.

I'm using this tool to convert: http://processingjs.org/tools/processing-helper.html

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a hard time tracking down **everything** that breaks between Processing 3 and Processing.js. They are two separate projects maintained by two separate groups of people.

The best thing you can do is try something, see specifically what breaks, and then try to find a workaround. Take each example one at a time, try to get it working, and post a question here if you get stuck on something specific.

That being said, one place to start looking for things that might not work is the [Changes in 3.0](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0) page on [Processing's GitHub](https://github.com/processing/processing).

Specifically, anything involving the new `surface` variable is not going to work in Processing.js. Similarly, the new `settings()` function won't work either. Some additional functions in `PVector` also won't work.

[Here](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/11928/javascript-mode-removed) is a link for a beta JavaScript mode for Processing 3, but you might be better off just waiting for Processing.js to catch up with Processing 3. In the meantime, take the examples one at a time, the workarounds shouldn't be too complicated to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Processing 3 (P3) is a java library, while processing.js (PJS) is a JS library, so each library will use their respective language's methods. As a basic example, a function in PJS will be declared like `function myFunction () {}` or in some cases `var myFunction = function () {};` while P3 would look like `void myFunction () {}`. 
Another difference is strong type, in JS you can simply declare any type of variable with `var myVariable = 0;` but in java and therefore P3, you need to use `int  myVariable = 0;` or `boolean myBoolean = false;`. 
Of course these aren't the only differences, but I hope they give you an idea of the differences in porting something from PJS to P3; while the library is very similar in both languages and can do many of the same things, it is mostly a difference between languages not libraries.